# Pass sbt settings as arguments in fullRunTask

Tags: sbt

How can I get the value of a setting (say, `name`) and pass it as an argument to `fullRunTask`? I do not understand the implementation of `fullRunTask`.

For example:

`lazy val foo = TaskKey[Unit]("foo")`

`fullRunTask(foo, Compile, "foo.Foo", name.value)`

does not work because I can't reference `name.value` in this context.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I don't understand the question. Could you show a piece of code you'd like to be able to execute, but it's not possible given your knowledge about SBT?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski see edit above

Comment: What do you need `fullRunTask` for?

Comment: I have a tool that runs project code and generates documentation, and I would like to configure this tool using SBT settings.

Comment: Why don't you create a task for the tool and have the setting `name` be its dependency?

Comment: Because I need to run project code with the project classpath. This is a custom `run` task.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I got some help from Josh Suereth. Doing this with `fullRunTask` is a little more complex but the extra stuff it does (adding `runner in myTask`) does wasn't really necessary. Inlining the body of `runTask` did what I needed.

```scala
lazy val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("my custom run task")

myTask := {
  val r = (runner in Compile).value
  val input = name.value // or any other string setting(s)
  val cp = (fullClasspath in Compile).value
  toError(r.run("my.MainClass", data(cp), Seq(input), streams.value.log))
}
```

Comment: It's great to know that the only way to achieve it is via a custom task that allows accessing values by `value`. I was to have answered it with this suggestion, but noticed I would've been late :)

Comment: Also, you need to add the "import sbt.Attributed.data" import to bring "data" in scope.